# How do I apply array methods to individual array that compose a two dimensional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

As a two dimensional array is an array of arrays, I needed to apply array methods `.unshift()` and `.pop()` to each individual array in a `2D array` of my JavaScript code.

Is there a way to do so? I know an individual member can be accessed by looping along `a[i][j]`, but how do I obtain the individual array for applying methods to it?

Example: I have an array:

```
var a = [
  [1,2,3]
  [4,5,6]
  [7,8,9]
]
```

Now in the first row I want to remove 3 from last and add 3 to the beginning giving me [3,1,2]. And do the same for all rows.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Do you have some code that you're having trouble with?

Comment: sample input ? sample output ? code ? please update your question with these to get proper answers

Comment: Sounds like you need to loop over your array, get every inner array and apply `unshift()` and `pop()` to it?

Comment: @NickParsons Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over your array using `.forEach()`, and then for each element in your array (ie: each inner array), `.pop()` the last element from the end of your array, and then use `.unshift(element)` to prepend the element you just popped off you're array:

```js
const a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

a.forEach(innerArray => {
  const last = innerArray.pop();
  innerArray.unshift(last);
});
console.log(a);
```

The above can be implemented using a regular for loop if you find that easier to understand:

```js
const a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  const innerArray = a[i];
  const last = innerArray.pop();
  innerArray.unshift(last);
}

console.log(a);
```

You can also do this by using `.map()`, which will produce a new array, leaving your original array `a` untouched:

```js
const a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

const a_new = a.map(inner => [inner.pop(), ...inner]);
console.log(a_new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Map it. Functional programming is cool!

```js
// to delete the first and last element of the inner array - `unshift` + `pop`
const result = someArray.map(innerArray => innerArray.slice(1, -1));
```